# Reloading UITableView after sending a POST

Tags: objective-c, ios

im trying to reload my UITableView after posting some data. Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)carregaLista{

NSError *err = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/tests/json/"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:theURL];
[request setURL:URL];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];

NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

resultsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

resultsDictionary = [jsonData objectFromJSONData];
//NSLog(@"my dictionary = %@", resultsDictionary);


self.billsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
self.billsArray = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"bills"];

// Add values to its array

double sum = [[self.billsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"] doubleValue];

NSString *totalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", sum];
self.total.text = totalString;

// Custom table cell

tabela.rowHeight = 100;
[self.tabela reloadData];
NSLog(@"Chamou carregaLista");

}
```

Then, in AddViewController:

```
-(IBAction)enviaCadastro:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"Nome: %@, Valor: %@", self.nome.text, self.valor.text);

NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/tests/json/add.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"nome=%@&valor=%@", self.nome.text, self.valor.text];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

float respCode = [responseString floatValue];
if(respCode < 400) {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    ViewController *firstView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [firstView carregaLista];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"NAO DEU CERTO");
}


}
```

What should I do to reload the table with the new added data?

Thanks.

Comment: Thats a lot of code, and you already have a call to `reloadData`, does this not work, or are you trying to reload it somewhere else besides the location you already are?

Comment: reloadData isnt working.

Comment: How are you sure it isn't working?  Is `tablea` nil at this point?

Comment: I assume isnt working because just after adding my entry, I try to reload it with the function `carregaLista`, but it seems not working, because it dont appears in the table.

Comment: I figured out that my billsArray is actually getting updated, so the problem is on refreshing the table. Could be maybe in numOfSections? Or the reloadData method should do this?

Comment: `reloadData` should be handling that, like I said, are you certain the  reference to `tablea` is not nil at the point you are calling `reloadData`?  Are you getting calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` on the table's data source after that call?  If not, then the method is not being invoked properly, or the data source is not set properly

Comment: If I quit the and opens it again, it reloads the table properly. I think cloud be something on `dataSource`. But isnt `dataSource` set properly if its working on startup?

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
ViewController *firstView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

...creates a **new** view controller which is a different instance from any you already had and is not the one with views that are visible on the screen.  You may be updating its data properties and expecting the updates to appear in your view.  I believe you need to call `carregaLista` on the `ViewController` that's already part of your app.

Comment: And am I not doing it? Calling `carregaLista`in ViewController? How should I do it?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that you're using more than one `ViewController` from what I read in your code.  Each instance has its own variables and properties which are not shared with others even if they're created from the same class.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. So, what you suggest to me?

Comment: You can prove whether or not I'm right by putting `NSLog(@"ViewController: %@", self);` inside `carregaLista`.  If it prints different addresses on different calls to it, then that's your problem.

Comment: Possibly you can pass a reference to the existing `ViewController` to `AddViewController` when you create it.  Or you could send a notification to the existing `ViewController` when something has changed and have it call `carregaLista` itself in `viewWillAppear:` if necessary.  There are probably other ways but I don't know how your program is structured.

Comment: NSLog returns to me on startup `<ViewController: 0x6896e50>` and `<ViewController: 0x6845ce0>` when i call the `carregaLista` from `AddViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain if this is the same case but I had a similar issue with the UIPickerView  `-reloadAllComponents` method.  I noticed that if the row went off screen then came back it updated.  Kind of what I expected the previous method to do.

The way I could get it to update was by removing what was in my NSMutableArray using the method `-removeAllObjects` then immediately call `-addObject:` then `-reloadAllComponents`.  I have a feeling you can do something similar and get the result you need.

Comment: Yes, I already tried out removingAllObjects of my `NSMutableArray` and dont works. In fact, the array its working properly, giving me the updated array of the data I just added. The problem its reloading/updating the table.

Comment: Ok my last guess.  I question if you are actually setting the `textLabel` and `text` properties correctly in your cells.

Comment: Yes, they are currently being added perfectly on my database.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. I was calling `carregaLista`inside of `viewDidLoad`. Just put inside of `viewWillAppear`then worked. Thanks to everybody.